# Testing js alert with Chai Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write a test that will pass if an alert pops up and fail if the alert fails to pop up.

I am using Mocha with Chai and Sinon.

Here is the function I'd like to test:

```
function generateAlert(x){    
    if(x){
        alert('X is true');
     } else { return}    
}
```

What I'm trying to do (psuedo):

```
describe('AlertView', function (){
    it('should create an alert only when x is true', function(){
        //check if alert is rendering and contains correct string
        chai.assert.alertHappens(generateAlert(True), 'X is true');
        //or at least check if alert happens at all
        chai.assert.alertHappens(generateAlert(True), true);
    }}
)}
```

I am new to Mocha Chai and I'm not sure how to check for the presence of an alert or check against the contents of an alert. I've looked through the Chai library and have not been able to find anything that can do this. Is there a Chai method that I've missed or some other way to check for alerts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `alert()` you are testing is a default `Window.alert` function you are testing. I would recommend you to take a look into [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) library which allows you to create [Spies](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinonspy) for your existing functions. So you can check if function was called, how many times and with what arguments.
I would overwrite `alert` in your code with a spy and just see that a proper argument was passed into alert.
Here is the code which works for me:

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var sinon = require('sinon');

var alert; // We are going to overwrite default alert() function

function generateAlert(x) {
  if (!x) {
    return;
  }

  alert(x);
}

describe('AlertView', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    alert = sinon.spy();
  });

  it('should create an alert only when x is true', function() {
    generateAlert(true);

    expect(alert.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(alert.args[0][0]).to.equal(true);
  });

  it('should create an alert only when x is some string', function() {
    generateAlert('X is true');

    expect(alert.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(alert.args[0][0]).to.equal('X is true');
  });

  it('should not create an alert only when x is false', function() {
    generateAlert();

    expect(alert.callCount).to.equal(0);
  });
});
```